# Trying to make dynamically populated linked select boxes to show specific images on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, select

I'm trying to create a form with dynamically populating select dropdowns, where when I select a car manufacturer, then the car model, I can click a go button (I know this can be done with a state change but I very specifically need a go button) an image of that specific car shows up on a frame on the same page, however I have got stuck at the go button section, can anyone help please?

```js
// object literal holding data for option elements
var Select_List_Data = {
  choices: {
    // name of associated select box

    // names match option values in controlling select box
    
    0: {
      text: ["Select Model..."],
      value: ["Select Model...", "0", "1"]
    },
    carA: {
      text: ["Select Model", "model i", "model ii", "model iii"],
      value: ["Select Model", "model i", "model ii", "model iii"]
    },
    carB: {
      text: ["Select Model", "model iv", "model v", "model vi"],
      value: ["Select Model", "model iv", "model v", "model vi"]
    },
    carC: {
      text: ["Select Model", "model vii", "model viii", "model ix"],
      value: ["Select Model", "model vii", "model viii", "model ix"]
    },
  }
};
// removes all option elements in select box
// removeGrp (optional) boolean to remove optgroups
function removeAllOptions(sel, removeGrp) {
  var len, groups, par;
  if (removeGrp) {
    groups = sel.getElementsByTagName("optgroup");
    len = groups.length;
    for (var i = len; i; i--) {
      sel.removeChild(groups[i - 1]);
    }
  }

  len = sel.options.length;
  for (var i = len; i; i--) {
    par = sel.options[i - 1].parentNode;
    par.removeChild(sel.options[i - 1]);
  }
}

function appendDataToSelect(sel, obj) {
  var f = document.createDocumentFragment();
  var labels = [],
    group,
    opts;

  function addOptions(obj) {
    var f = document.createDocumentFragment();
    var o;

    for (var i = 0, len = obj.text.length; i < len; i++) {
      o = document.createElement("option");
      o.appendChild(document.createTextNode(obj.text[i]));

      if (obj.value) {
        o.value = obj.value[i];
      }

      f.appendChild(o);
    }
    return f;
  }

  if (obj.text) {
    opts = addOptions(obj);
    f.appendChild(opts);
  } else {
    for (var prop in obj) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        labels.push(prop);
      }
    }

    for (var i = 0, len = labels.length; i < len; i++) {
      group = document.createElement("optgroup");
      group.label = labels[i];
      f.appendChild(group);
      opts = addOptions(obj[labels[i]]);
      group.appendChild(opts);
    }
  }
  sel.appendChild(f);
}
// anonymous function assigned to onchange event of controlling select box
document.forms["demoForm"].elements["category"].onchange = function(e) {
  // name of associated select box
  var relName = "choices";

  // reference to associated select box
  var relList = this.form.elements[relName];

  // get data from object literal based on selection in controlling select box (this.value)
  var obj = Select_List_Data[relName][this.value];

  // remove current option elements
  removeAllOptions(relList, true);

  // call function to add optgroup/option elements
  // pass reference to associated select box and data for new options
  appendDataToSelect(relList, obj);
};

// populate associated select box as page loads
(function() {
  // immediate function to avoid globals

  var form = document.forms["demoForm"];

  // reference to controlling select box
  var sel = form.elements["category"];
  sel.selectedIndex = 0;

  // name of associated select box
  var relName = "choices";
  // reference to associated select box
  var rel = form.elements[relName];

  // get data for associated select box passing its name
  // and value of selected in controlling select box
  var data = Select_List_Data[relName][sel.value];

  // add options to associated select box
  appendDataToSelect(rel, data);
})();
```

```html
<form action="#" method="post" id="demoForm" class="demoForm">

        <label class="wrapper" for="states">Target Manufacturer</label>
    <div class="button dropdown"> 
        <select name="category">
          <option value="0" selected="selected">Select a Manufacturer...</option>
<option value="carA">car a</option>
<option value="carB">car b</option>
<option value="carC">car c</option>
        </select>  </div>
<div><label class="wrapper" for="states">Model</label>
       <div class="button dropdown">  <select name="choices" id="choices">
            <!-- populated using JavaScript -->
        </select></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use external json files if you have long lists of data, but if you are changing between short lists, use arrays to populate your select option. 
You can use a short jquery function to get the selected (filtered) option and to display that image based on the selection.

I include code (with a placeholder image) and a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/3o52y69h/)

(There's a small glitch in the code that I just realised I hadn't accounted for while posting - but you can fix it - [onchange] doesn't work on the first option. A check for the selectedindex  will sort it!)

Only the Ford options populate for demo purposes.

Hope this helps

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //init data
  var arrayList = [{
      "Id": 0,
      "Name": "Please select an option"
    },
    {
      "Id": 1,
      "Name": "Ford"
    },
    {
      "Id": 2,
      "Name": "Jaguar"
    },
    {
      "Id": 3,
      "Name": "VW"
    }
  ];


  for (var i = 0; i <= arrayList.length; i++) {
    $('#choices').append('<option value="' + arrayList[i].Id + '">' + arrayList[i].Name + '</option>');
  }


});

$("#choices").change(function() {
  // $.getJSON("jsondata/data.json", function(data) {
  //use this if using external json sets
  
  var $selection = $("#choices option:selected");
  var key = $selection.val();

  var vals = [];
  
  $(".imghere").attr("src", "");

  switch (key) {
    case '1':
      vals = ["Fiesta", "Focus", " Mustang"]; //you can list your values in arrays if you want e.g. vals=["Fiesta", "Focus", "Mustang"] but if you have a lot of values, then it may be easier to read values in from an external file
      break;
    case '2':
      vals = ["I don't own a Jag"] //data.Jaguar.split(",");
      break;
    case '3':
      vals = ["5-series", "7-series"] //data.VW.split(",");
      break;
    case '0':
      vals = ['Please choose a category'];
  }

  var $secondChoice = $("#filter");
  $secondChoice.empty();
  $.each(vals, function(index, value) {
    $secondChoice.append("<option>" + value + "</option>");
  });

});


$("#filter").change(function() {
  var $filter = $("#filter option:selected").val();
  var baseurl = "https://www.yourdomain.com/images/";
  var $showimg = baseurl + $filter + ".jpg";
  //$(".imghere").attr("src",$showimg); use this, the next line is demo purposes
  $(".imghere").attr("src", "https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5a6def0aace864bfafe27afe/t/5a6e72bc085229bac52f23be/1518455566354/Fiesta.jpg"); /*use variable in place of the placeholder image*/

});
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
}

h4 {
  margin: 5px 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#choices,
#filter {
  margin-bottom: 9px;
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
}

#imagehere {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  top: 40vh;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 1px dashed grey;
}

.imghere {
  opacity: 1;
  width:225px;
  height:auto;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>
  Category
</h4>
<select id="choices">

</select>

<h4>
  Filter
</h4>
<select id="filter">

</select>

<div id="imagehere">
  <img class="imghere" src="" alt="filtered category">

</div>
```

Comment: TI will be using long lists of data, for this instance I cut it down to minimise the script I was posting. Regardless, this is fantastic, thank you so much for this, it's exactly what I need, now just to incorporate a "go button" but I should hopefully be able to work that out myself!

Comment: @BJG you are welcome. Use json lists then, and store them in as external json files. It's easier than it sounds!